# 'const' array to function - C++

Tags: function, pointers, parameters, constants

I defined a function to calculate the distance between 2 points in 2D, these points being arrays of 2 elements. My "distance" function gives me different results when passing the arrays as constant, or not, in the function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

double distance(const double *x1,const double *x2)
{
double dist;
dist=sqrt((x1[0]-x2[0])*(x1[0]-x2[0]) + (x1[1]-x2[1])*(x1[1]-x2[1]));
return dist;
}

double distance1(double *x1,double *x2)
{
double dist;
dist=sqrt((x1[0]-x2[0])*(x1[0]-x2[0]) + (x1[1]-x2[1])*(x1[1]-x2[1]));
return dist;
}

int main() {
double x1[2],x2[2];
double val;
x1[0]=1;x1[1]=0;
x2[0]=0;x2[1]=1;

val=distance(x1,x2);
cout << val << endl;
val=distance1(x1,x2);
cout << val << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Doing so I get :

-2

1.41421

I don't understand why the "distance" function does not do the same as "distance1". I would expect the same result but "distance" preventing me from modifying the content of the x1 and x2 arrays.

Also, when naming both function "distance", I get the expected results (1.41421), which function is then called in that case ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case will be called the function [std::distance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/) that returns the distance between iterators:

```
template<class InputIterator>
  typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
    distance (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Just a bad name choice for a function ;)

[EDITED] As [Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707650/evert) pointed, please take a look at [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice